# Should emails in MongoDB be stored as lowercase?

Tags: mongodb

If you are building a system that uses the email address as a username, should that be stored in lowercase due to MongoDB's case sensitivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky question since emails are actually case sensitive: http://email.about.com/gi/o.htm?zi=1/XJ&zTi=1&sdn=email&cdn=compute&tm=84&f=00&tt=12&bt=5&bts=45&zu=http%3A//www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2821.html

> The local-part of a mailbox MUST BE treated as case sensitive. Therefore, SMTP implementations MUST take care to preserve the case of mailbox local-parts.

So:

```
localhost@local.com
```

is different to:

```
LocalHost@local.com
```

As such whether you treat these two differently is up to your scenario. Either way there is no straight answer and however unlikely it is you could one day run into someone who has a duplicate email address if you decide to store in a standard manner like lower case.

Also many mail server won't actually deliver to the right inbox in such a scenario.

Comment: Yes I am suprised there isn't more information about this already. A lot of major mail servers ignore case so localHost@local.com would go to the same mailbox as LOCALHOST@local.com even though the standard says otherwise. The problem lies when the user tries to login with a different case than what he/she used to signup. The only way I would run a successful find is to use a regex which is probably not very efficient (will look into this). So lowercase seems like the best option.

Comment: @Xerri yes in this case storing standardised as lower case would be best bet. You don't have to store two fields if you don't plan on ever using the original email the user inputted which 90% is the case since their email is private etc etc

Answer (score 4):

Due to case sensitivity in Mongo, you should have a few choices as to how to proceed.

1. Use regex to search for the users username/email:

   `db.users.find( { "email" : { "$regex" : "foo@bar.com", "$options" : "-i" } })`
2. The next option would be to duplicate the email field into a lowercase version in the dataset and then use find as one would usually:

   `users { email, emailLower, ... }`
3. An alternative is to just lowercase the input on save and then again on lookup.

Admittedly they all are a bit roundabout, however the regex option can actually prove to be a little slow. I would recommend the third personally.

Comment: that's what I've got going. Don't think regex is a viable solution. The lowercase seems like the best one.